# Hashing two different Tuples filled with different netaddr objects gives same hash value

Tags: python, object, hash

When trying to hash a Tuple of netaddr objects, it yelds the same hash value, even if the included objects is different.

What is the recommended way of hashing a tuple of netaddr objects?

```
>>> from netaddr import IPRange
>>> from netaddr import IPNetwork
>>> (IPRange('36.0.0.0', '36.255.255.255'), IPNetwork('36.0.0.0/8')).__hash__()
-339953817
>>> (IPRange('38.0.0.0', '38.255.255.255'), IPNetwork('38.0.0.0/8')).__hash__()
-339953817
```

(Python 2.7.10 in Windows was used)

Comment: Are you sure `IPRange` and `IPNetwork` support hashing?

Comment: I'm getting different hashes on the above code. I'm on 2.7.10 with macOS, maybe it's an implementation quirk?

Comment: From a quick look, it doesn't look like `netaddr.IPRange` or `netaddr.IPNetwork` actually have their own `__hash__` method. `netaddr.IPNetwork` is even mutable!

Comment: On a second look, they seem to be inheriting [`BaseIP.__hash__`](https://github.com/drkjam/netaddr/blob/4205371c4e09eb4e22c3ff62083fb595a78f9442/netaddr/ip/__init__.py#L56), not `object.__hash__`. `IPNetwork` really shouldn't support that, what with the mutability and all.

Comment: If they're using identity based hashing, the fact that you don't keep any references to the tuple around may be significant. Running `hash(object())` twice could give you the same results, since the object instances are not alive at the same time and the memory can be reused.